# Quoting/protecting special characters piped to bash?

Tags: bash, pipe, special-characters, quoting

I have

```
$ cat afile 
file(1).txt ./adir

$ cat question.sh 
#!/bin/bash

sed -e 's/^/mv /' afile | bash

$ ./question.sh 
bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: line 1: `mv file(1).txt ./adir'
```

How do I protect the line being piped into `bash`, for the special characters like `()` in the filename `file(1).txt` ? There can be other special characters that I am not aware of in advance, so I am looking for a generic way to do this that handles all characters.

Comment: Why are `(` and `)` to be protected but not `\ ` (space)?  Without an explanation of your rules, it's hard to give a satisfactory answer...

Comment: @TobySpeight The question is very simple and straighforward.

Comment: It's *too* simple - completely underspecified.

Comment: @TobySpeight Please help me understand what is not clear over here: *"How do I protect the line being piped into bash, for the special characters like () in the filename file(1).txt ? There can be other special characters that I am not aware of in advance, so I am looking for a generic way to do this that handles all characters."*

Comment: You seem to be using spaces (and/or tabs? it's not clear) and newlines to delimit items in your `afile`; how do you represent those characters when they occur within the file names?  Which other other characters do you want to escape?  (e.g. `\?*{}$~` etc)

Answer (score 1):

Modifying a text file to be a script is very difficult to do properly. An easier way is to [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), read the lines of that file, and run the operation directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -u 9 source target
do
    mv "$source" "$target"
done 9< afile
```

This will handle most filenames, except those starting with a dash. It also assumes that filenames are separated by space or tab, so whitespace in either filename is going to break except for rare exceptions.

Comment: You can handle filenames beginning with `-` quite easily: `mv -- "$source" "$target"`.  Dealing with filenames that contain spaces or newlines is going to be much harder.

Comment: @TobySpeight That solution is completely application specific; many applications do not support the double dash separator. Supporting filenames with newlines would mean changing the input file, but if you use NUL character separators it's as simple as adding `-d ''` to `read`.

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes are your friend. Here's an updated `question.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -e 's/^/mv /' -e 's/(/\\(/g' -e 's/)/\\)/g' afile | bash
```

You can extend the pattern for other metacharacters like spaces and so on.

Comment: This is not a generic answer because there can be other special characters that I am not aware of in advance.

Comment: You can make the substitution more extensible using a character group (and GNU sed can even execute the command if you want): `s/^/mv /`; `s/\(["(){}$*?\\']\)/\\\1/ge`